Sidebar doesn't appear when gesture detector it is touched
I have a flutter app and I added in the homepage , at the appbar a container and when it's pressed nothing happens. I also use rive animation but I don't know if this is the reason it is affected .There is a onMenuPress, onMenuInit, the initState but I don't know what it should be changed.. here it's the code :
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  late Animation<double> _sidebarAnim;
  late SMIBool _menuBtn;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> tabItems = [
    Center(child: Text("0")),
    Center(child: Text("1")),
    Center(child: Text("2")),
    Center(child: Text("3")),
    Center(child: Text("4"))
  ];
  final springDesc =
      const SpringDescription(mass: 0.1, stiffness: 40, damping: 5);

  void _onMenuIconInit(Artboard artboard) {
    final controller =
        StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, "State Machine");
    artboard.addController(controller!);
    _menuBtn = controller.findInput<bool>("isOpen") as SMIBool;
    _menuBtn.value = true;
  }

  void onMenuPress() {
    if (_menuBtn.value) {
      final springAnim = SpringSimulation(springDesc, 0, 1, 0);
      _animationController?.animateWith(springAnim);
    } else {
      _animationController?.reverse();
    }
    _menuBtn.change(!_menuBtn.value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      upperBound: 1,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _sidebarAnim = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear));

    // _tabBody = _screens.first;
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _handleRefresh() async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: <Widget>[
          AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _sidebarAnim,
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(_sidebarAnim.value * 265, 0),
                  child: child,
                );
              }),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: onMenuPress,
            child: Container(
              width: 70,
              height: 70,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70 / 2),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: RiveAppTheme.shadow.withOpacity(0.2),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 5))
                  ]),
              child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                '/Users/lilianasanda/influfit/assets/rive/menu_button.riv',
                stateMachines: const ["State Machine"],
                animations: const ["open", "close"],
                onInit: _onMenuIconInit,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],


you might be missing of calling AnimatedBuilder(...,child:YourWidget

Where? in the AnimatedBuilder?

yap, More about AnimatedBuilder

I added SideMenu() But it gives a big error

sorry I am not clear about desire ux, if you've already animated on rive, StateMachineController can be used to toggle animation. It will be easier if you could the full minimal snippet on gist/dartPad with rive file or just invite to the gitRepo(yeasin50) so that I can test and reproduce the same error
